# JPA/Hibernate + Postgres SequenceGenerator

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, sequence

I'm trying for the all day long get the Sequence from a Postgres with JPA/Hibernate, but it gives me all the time:

INFO: Hibernate: 
    call next value for tb_cdr_id_seq
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "call"
SEVERE: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_cdr")
@XmlRootElement
@SequenceGenerator(name = "tb_cdr_id_seq", sequenceName = "tb_cdr_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
public class Cdr implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tb_cdr_id_seq")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
....

}
```

the Postgres version is 9.2 and don't have the function: call next value.... like Hibernate is print...

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the SQL Hibernate is generating and the full, exact error. See the PostgreSQL logs (`log_statement = on`) or Hibernate logs. At a guess, you might be using the wrong SQL dialect setting, or the sequence `tb_cdr_id_seq` doesn't exist.

Comment: <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/> done the trick! Tks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate wasn't auto-detecting the dialect or it was being overridden. Setting `hibernate.dialect` explicitly to `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` resolved the issue.